# Does Undertale need WiFi or Playstation Plus on PS4?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus, undertale

Does the PS4 version of Undertale need wifi or PlayStation Plus?

I made a mistake by buying PvZ: GardenWarfare on PS4, a game which can't be played without PS Plus.

Also, how can I tell if a PS4 game requires PlayStation Plus?

Answer (score 3):

PlayStation Plus is only required for multiplayer games with online functionality.

Undertale is an offline single player RPG, so it does not require PlayStation Plus.

Comment: Finally someone answered! (not meaning to be rude, just happy to be honest) Thank you Steven Vascellaro!

Comment: @user195483 My pleasure. If this answered your question you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark

Comment: But where can I find the check mark?

Comment: @user195483 The check mark is located to the left of an answer, directly below the up and down arrows

Comment: Steven Vascellaro, unfortunately I cannot do it right now, I am currently a guest. But I just made an account, named Russeladrian. This question is answered for me by you, thank you very much!